# javascript push to 1 array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push new values to an array, but when the values are pushed 2 new arrays are  created. I am trying to push the values into one array not in separate ones. How do I do that? Here is the code I am using.

```
for (count = 0; count < xmlItem.length; count++) {
  // dates
  xmlDate = new Date(xmlItem[count].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  // titles
  xmlTitle = xmlItem[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  // descriptions
  xmlDescription = xmlItem[count].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  // date reformated
  pubDate = (xmlDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + xmlDate.getDate() + "/" + xmlDate.getFullYear();
  // if there is a new code
  if (pubDate == today) {
      // array with titles for new values
      totalValues = new Array();
      // add the title
      totalValues.push(xmlTitle);
      // add badge for number of values
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: JSON.stringify(totalValues.length) });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this `totalCodes = new Array();` before your `for` loop.

Each time your `for` loop is iterating, it's creating new array with `totalCodes = new Array();`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you execute the loop, the line `totalCodes = new Array()` is called, resetting `totalCodes` to an empty array.  Declare `totalCodes` outside of your `for` loop.